# most efficient code for printing odd numbers from 1-99

Tags: python

The task is to print the odd numbers from 1-99 on separate lines.

Codeeval deemed this code partially correct (98 out of 100): (edited)

```
liszt = (i for i in range(1,100) if i%2!=0)
for i in liszt:
    print i
```

Codeeval deemed the below code completely correct:

```
liszt = range(1,100)
for i in liszt:
    if i%2!=0:
        print i
```

New to Python, so just looking to understand why one method might be considered better than the other. Is the second method more efficient?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `print '\n'.join(map(str, xrange(1, 100, 2)))`

Comment: `range(1-100)` returns an empty list, doesn't it?

Comment: So to answer your question: the first method scores less since it doesn't print the same (correct) output as the second one like bnjmn observed. It should be `range(1, 100)` there as well.

Comment: Apologies @bnjmn and @Benjamin, that's just a typo I had put in the question. The original code I had entered for Codeeval used `range(1,100)` .

Comment: I'm curious as to why you got a 98 as well. I recently checked out `code_eval` and I don't think there is a penalty in the final score for speed or efficiency (there are other metrics for that). If you got a 98, you must have missed exactly 1 of the 50 odds  numbers from 1 to 99; hence the -2. Just curious if there was another typo or something.

Comment: @bnjmn, that sounds likely. I may have forgotten that the second argument in the `range()` function is exclusive (i.e. I put 99 instead of 100)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the first code you are iterating over two generators first `range(1, 100)` and then over `liszt` whereas in the second case the iteration is only over `liszt`. Other than that the operation is same in both the cases, so the second method is more efficient.

Since every second number after 1 would be odd, a better solution could be:

```
for i in range(1, 100, 2):
    print(i)
```

Comment: The question is why Codeeval would have chosen the second example as "more correct" then the first example.  This doesn't answer that.  It gives a third example.

Answer (score 0):

```
print("\n".join(str(i) for i in range(1,100,2)))
```

Comment: The question is why Codeeval would have chosen the second example as "more correct" then the first example.  This doesn't answer that.  It gives a third example.